# How to get 2nd highest status in mongodb with a collection having multiple status

Tags: mongodb, aggregation-framework, query-optimization

```
    /* 1 */
    {
        "_id" : ObjectId("5f0b6699486ea60a2a9c62fh"),
        "EventDatetime" : "2020-07-12T19:38:00.653",
        "Eventstatus" : "05",
        "DelNumber" : "0703676929",
        "DELIVERY_ITEM" : [ 
            {
                "Product_Code" : "123",
                "Product_Name" : "utensils",
                "Shipment_Quantity" : "12",
            }, 
            {
                "Product_Code" : "456",
                "Product_Name" : "clothes",
                "Shipment_Quantity" : "10",
            }
        ]
    }
    {
        "_id" : ObjectId("5f0b6699486ea60a2a9c62fi"),
        "EventDatetime" : "2020-07-12T19:38:00.653",
        "Eventstatus" : "03",
        "DelNumber" : "0703676929",,
        "DELIVERY_ITEM" : [ 
            {
                "Product_Code" : "123",
                "Product_Name" : "utensils",
                "Shipment_Quantity" : "12",
            }, 
            {
                "Product_Code" : "456",
                "Product_Name" : "clothes",
                "Shipment_Quantity" : "10",
            }
        ]
    }
    {
        "_id" : ObjectId("5f0b6699486ea60a2a9c62fg"),
        "EventDatetime" : "2020-07-12T19:38:00.653",
        "Eventstatus" : "02",
        "DelNumber" : "0703676929",
        "DELIVERY_ITEM" : [ 
            {
                "Product_Code" : "123",
                "Product_Name" : "utensils",
                "Shipment_Quantity" : "12",
            }, 
            {
                "Product_Code" : "456",
                "Product_Name" : "clothes",
                "Shipment_Quantity" : "10",
            }
        ]
    }
    /*2*/

    {
        "_id" : ObjectId("5f0b6699486ea60a2a9c62fa"),
        "EventDatetime" : "2020-07-12T19:38:00.653",
        "Eventstatus" : "04",
        "DelNumber" : "0703676928",
        "DELIVERY_ITEM" : [ 
            {
                "Product_Code" : "123",
                "Product_Name" : "utensils",
                "Shipment_Quantity" : "12",
            }, 
            {
                "Product_Code" : "456",
                "Product_Name" : "clothes",
                "Shipment_Quantity" : "10",
            }
        ]
    }
    {
        "_id" : ObjectId("5f0b6699486ea60a2a9c62fb"),
        "EventDatetime" : "2020-07-12T19:38:00.653",
        "Eventstatus" : "02",
        "DelNumber" : "0703676928",
        "DELIVERY_ITEM" : [ 
            {
                "Product_Code" : "123",
                "Product_Name" : "utensils",
                "Shipment_Quantity" : "12",
            }, 
            {
                "Product_Code" : "456",
                "Product_Name" : "clothes",
                "Shipment_Quantity" : "10",
            }
        ]
    }
    {
        "_id" : ObjectId("5f0b6699486ea60a2a9c62fc"),
        "EventDatetime" : "2020-07-12T19:38:00.653",
        "Eventstatus" : "01",
        "DelNumber" : "0703676928",
        "DELIVERY_ITEM" : [ 
            {
                "Product_Code" : "123",
                "Product_Name" : "utensils",
                "Shipment_Quantity" : "12",
            }, 
            {
                "Product_Code" : "456",
                "Product_Name" : "clothes",
                "Shipment_Quantity" : "10",
            }
        ]
    }
```

I am having a collection for orders. Consider it like a ecommerce site. Now, order can have multiple status 00,01,02,03,04 and 05 . 05 refers to live tracking of the order . So my delno.1 can have status 01,02,05,05,03,05,05. My problem is how can I get a query which I run gives 03 as latest status not 05.
Also when the status reaches 04 that record I don't need to get on retrieval.
Any help will be great!!

Comment: Can you add your order record in the question ?

Comment: $push with $slice(2) after ordering the documents.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to first remove all documents which have status 04. Then do a lookup on the same collection to get the remaining documents. Unwind it and filter out documents with status 05.

```
[
  {
    //Group records by DelNumber
    $group: {
      _id: '$DelNumber',
      EventStatuses: {
        $addToSet: '$Eventstatus'
      }
    }
  }, {
    // Remove any with status 04
    $match: {
      EventStatuses: {
        $ne: '04'
      }
    }
  }, {
    // Looksup on same collection to get full document
    $lookup: {
      from: 'collection',
      localField: '_id',
      foreignField: 'DelNumber',
      as: 'matched'
    }
  }, {
    // Unwind the matched records
    $unwind: {
      path: '$matched'
    }
  }, {
    $replaceRoot: {
      newRoot: '$matched'
    }
  }, {
    // Remove any record with status 05
    $match: {
      Eventstatus: {
        $ne: '05'
      }
    }
  }
]
```

Answer (score 2):

You can try,

- `$match` your conditions, DelNumber is "0703676929" and Eventstatus not equal to 4th
- `$addFields` to add Eventstatus in integer field using `$toInt`
- `$sort` by status field in descending order
- `$skip` in second page (1) because first is 5 status
- `$limit` single record

```
db.collection.aggregate([
  { 
    $match: { 
      DelNumber: "0703676929",
      Eventstatus: { $ne: "04" } 
    } 
  }, 
  { $addFields: { status: { $toInt: "$Eventstatus" } } },
  { $sort: { status: -1 } },
  { $skip: 1 },
  { $limit: 1 }
])
```

[Playground](https://mongoplayground.net/p/tcDLp6gZkZG)

---

Second way you can use fix condition in 5th status,

- `$match` your conditions, DelNumber is "0703676929" and Eventstatus not equal to 4th and 5th
- `$addFields` to add Eventstatus in integer field using `$toInt`
- `$sort` by status field in descending order
- `$limit` single record

```
db.collection.aggregate([
  {
    $match: {
      DelNumber: "0703676929",
      Eventstatus: { $nin: ["05", "04"] }
    }
  },
  { $addFields: { status: { $toInt: "$Eventstatus" } } },
  { $sort: { status: -1 } },
  { $limit: 1 }
])
```

[Playground](https://mongoplayground.net/p/Q_JwGL-WzE6)